# Why it pop the newest pushed element from Queue in CLion

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, queue, clion

I write a Queue (Initialized as [1,2,3]) in CLion (Mac Version), but I really don't know why after pop() , it shows the remaining elements is **[1,2]** in the below debug window, instead of **[2,3]**. I check the front() step by step, looks like they are correct. Someone can help me explain what's wrong?[image]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Since `front()` is returning the correct thing, it looks like the problem is with the CLion debugger, not the code.

Comment: @user4581301 The specification of `queue::pop()` says it calls `pop_front()` on the underlying container, so it should be removing the element.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. If the `queue` is following the usual behavior of being based around a `deque`, that 1 is still there. The head pointer is just moved to the next element. I think the debugger doesn't realize this and is still using the start of the block, not the head of the queue, for display purposes.

Comment: So the problem is the debugger? Sometimes I need the debugger to check the intermediate running status. What can I do for this kind problem?

Comment: Seems issue is reported on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11356